# How does latexmk find package files?

Tags: packages, latexmk

I installed TexLive on Arch Linux together with `texlive-latexextra` in order to use the package `todonotes`, but `latexmk` does not find the `todonotes.sty` file. This is what it prints:

$ latexmk --

```
pdf latex-preview.tex 
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 5 February 2015, version: 4.43a.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'latex-preview.pdf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "latex-preview.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./latex-preview.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))

! LaTeX Error: File `todonote.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

I located it manually, it is in `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/`.

For some reason, this folder has not been added to the locations `latexmk` searches for sty files.

So, how does `latexmk` look for sty files and how do I add folders for it to search through?

Running `texhash` gives this:

```
texhash: Updating /etc/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

But it does not work after that or after rebooting..

`texhash` claims to watch `ls -R /usr/share/texmf-dist/`. It should find it in there, considering this:

```
$ ls -R /usr/share/texmf-dist/ | grep todonotes
fixmetodonotes
todonotes
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fixmetodonotes:
fixmetodonotes.sty
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes:
todonotes.sty
luatodonotes
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luatodonotes:
luatodonotes.lua
luatodonotes.sty
todonotes-xetex-bidi.def
```

And

```
$ kpsewhich todonotes.sty
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
! LaTeX Error: File `todonote.sty' not found.
```

and

```
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes:
todonotes.sty
```

one has an s and one does not....